Multiple Error: after using "sudo apt update"
After using "sudo apt update" multiple error occurred, tried to get solution in stack overflow and Ask Ubuntu but couldn't found any. Really new in this community it will be appreciable.
Err:2 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0686B78420038257
Err:8 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_23.10  InRelease
The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1488EB46E192A257 home:manuelschneid3r OBS Project home:manuelschneid3r@build.opensuse.org
Err:9 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04  InRelease
The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E07629B9E3C9E4 home:pzz OBS Project home:pzz@build.opensuse.org
Err:13 https://apt.packages.shiftkey.dev/ubuntu any InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7FC979028B1997C1
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0686B78420038257
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
I tried multiple options from Ask Ubuntu and stack overflow

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0686B784200382
/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.b8cdJNAbsB/gpg.1.sh --keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0686B784200382
/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.b8cdJNAbsB/gpg.1.sh --keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0686B784200382


Apparently, brave's release key changed from D8BAD4DE7EE17AF52A834B2D0BB75829C2D4E821 to DBF1A116C220B8C7164F98230686B78420038257, but I haven't found any official confirmation yet. I recommend waiting until they confirm the key change through an trustworthy platform (might be a supply chain attack)

@canochordo how do you know? I don't think it's getting resolved, maybe Brave forum, but I don't feel like going through the ordeal of signing up

same key: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1514034/multiple-errors-while-using-sudo-apt-update

Purge the current installation
apt purge brave-browser brave-keyring;  rm /etc/pt/sources.list.d/shiftkey-packages.list
Then reinstall from the brave website
    curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg
    echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main"|sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
    apt update
    apt install brave-browser
(add sudo as appropriate).
You might further wish to edit the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list and add arch=amd64 within the square brackets.
You can modify the echo command to include it to bypass the edit step.
The ach=amd64 edit is necessary to quiet the
Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages'
informational message since there is no i386 package.
